# Eloquent Query by Month and Count each value

Tags: php, laravel, view, eloquent

I am trying to build a query to show medications used by month for the last 6 months for each group of medications.

The returned query should look something like.

medication | October | September | August | July | June | May
1               2           1       4         6      2     1
2               2           1       4         6      2     1
3               2           1       4         6      2     1
4               2           1       4         6      2     1

I have started to write a query like...

```
<?php

$nw = NarcoticWaste::with([
    'vial' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('medication', DB::raw('count(*) as use_count')); //I am unaware how to get each month here//);
        $query->groupBy('medication');
    },
    'vial.medications'
])->withCount(['vial'])->get();

foreach ($nw as $n) {
    $n->vial_count;
}
```

I have searched and found methods to group by month but haven't found anything to make a column for each month.

Comment: `foreach($nw as $nw` shouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$nw = NarcoticWaste::with(['vial' => function($query) 
    {
        $query->select('medication', DB::Raw('MONTH(created_at) month'),DB::raw('count(*) as use_count'));
        $query->groupBy('medication', 'month');
    }, 'vial.medications'])
        ->withCount(['vial'])
        ->get();

    foreach($nw as $n)
    {
        $n->month;
        $n->medication;
        $n->use_count; 
    }
```

Where `DB::Raw('MONTH(created_at)` will get the month, and `$query->groupBy('medication', 'month');` will group per medication and per month.

Comment: Ok this appears to work as it did produce the correct query. "select `medication`, MONTH(created_at) month, count(*) as use_count from `controlled_substances` where `controlled_substances`.`id` in ('259', '260') group by `medication`, `month` " and the result is right. When i do a dd() on any of the month medication or count I get null.  I have tried to show the results on the view by running the same foreach that is on the controller with no result shown.

Comment: Could you post more information about the foreach which shows no results?

Comment: foreach($nw as $n)
    {
        $n->month;
        $n->medication;
        $n->use_count; 
    }

Comment: It could be a lot of things, maybe check that the data is present. If you can't find it open a new question and add all related information to it. Thanks.

Comment: I managed to get the data out now when I display it to the chart if one of the meds does not have any data for a particular month it scues the chart.